# How to add access to certain service account, specific Google Storage Bucket via Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I make automation when storage buckets should be created automatically. It nails down to create if it doesn't exist and applies correct IAM policies.

In `gsutil` I can do it by:

```
gsutil acl ch -u john.doe@example.com:WRITE gs://example-bucket
gsutil acl ch -u john.doe@example.READ gs://example-bucket
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to the same in Python. I looked through GitHub, StackOverflow, and official docs and don't see the way.

I create a bucket `client.create_bucket(bucket_name)` [based on the official python library and examples from there](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/)

Comment: Maybe you need something like this: [https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access) to assign policy automatically to any newly created buckets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [google-cloud-storage](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/acl.html)

Here is an example code:

```
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    acl = bucket.acl

    # For user
    acl.user("me@example.org").grant_read()
    acl.all_authenticated().grant_write()

    # For service account
    acl.service_account("example@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com").grant_read()

    acl.save()
    print(list(acl))
```